# Combining tables in SQLITE while directly replacing values from another table

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite db with 4 tables. I now want to retrieve the contents of one of them and replace the contents of one of its rows with the respective content of one of the other tables and then return the result.

E.g.

Table 1:

Row0,         Row1,          Row2,        ...,  Row20

'some numbers'  'some numbers'   'name string'  ....  'some numbers'

Table 2:

Row0,        Row1

'name string'  'name (cleaned and formatted)'

So every time I access a row in table 1 instead of returning the value for Table1.Row2 it should return my the corresponding value of Table2.Row1 if there is no such value then just use the existing one from Table1.Row2

Just using
select * from table1 inner join row2 on table1.row2 = table2.row0 doesn't work.

If this question has already been answered, I'm happy to head over to the post, yet I have no clue on how to search for my problem, which is why I'm writing it here.

Thanks
Liz

Comment: Please add sample _table_ data for both tables.

Comment: Naming columns *Rowx* is certainly legal, but at least confusing for the reader!

Comment: You requirement is *unclear*. SQLite is a **relational** database, so it is easy to model relations between tables with `JOIN`. But you failed to explain how a row in table1 should be linked to a row in table2. Remember: order in a table has no reason to be consistent unless you specifically require it.

Comment: [LEFT JOIN](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause) and [The CASE expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)